# Can a ContentView receive focus?

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin.forms, uwp, tizen

I have an element that I want to become highlighted when navigated to with a D-pad and respond to an "enter" button. I assumed I could do this with a focused element and am trying to set up my `ContentView` to handle such interaction.

The `ContentView` class inherits from `VisualElement` and has a `Focus()` method. The documentation states that for the `Focus()` method to work, the "[element] must be able to receive focus."

How can I make an element "able to receive focus"? It doesn't appear to work in UWP or Tizen with this bare-bones example. Tabbing, clicking, arrow keys, programmatically setting the focus... Nothing sets `IsFocused` to true, and my callback is never called.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyProject.Components
{
    public class FocusMe : ContentView
    {
        public FocusMe ()
        {
            Content = new StackLayout {
                Children = {
                    new Label { Text = "Welcome to Xamarin.Forms!" }
                }
            };
            Focused += FocusMe_Focused;
            Task.Run(async () => {
                await Task.Delay(5000);
                Focus(); // false
                _ = IsFocused; // false
            });
        }

        private void FocusMe_Focused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
        {
            // never called
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK "focus" means being able to receive keyboard input - editors and entry, etc

Comment: @Jason that makes sense. In my specific use case, it's an element that I want to become highlighted when navigated to with a D-pad and respond to an "enter" button. Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can a ContentView receive focus?

Base on the testing, `ContentView` will not receive `Focused` event. However, `Frame` layout could receive focused event, and frame inherits from `ContentView`, you could use [`Frame`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/frame) to replace. Please note, you need to place focusable control in it such as button.

Answer (score 1):

If you work on Tizen TV, How about check [TV.UIControls](https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen.TV.UIControls), it is a extension library for TV applications

If do you want to react a key event on a view, I recommend to use `ContentButton` view on TV.UIControls
It is based on `ContentView` but works like a button

Here is a guide
https://samsung.github.io/Tizen.TV.UIControls/guides/ContentButton.html